# problemas com php, json, javascript e mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json

Estou tentando buscar dados do `mysql` para exibir no `html` com `php` utilizando `json`, mas esta dando errado, ele traz os dados mas não exibe, se eu aperto o f12 ele mostra os dados do banco mas não exibe os dados.

segue o codigo:
 index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
 var url="ajax.php";
 $.getJSON(url,function(result){
 console.log(result);
 $.each(result, function(i, field){
 var id=field.id;
 var nome=field.nome;
 $("#listview").append(id+nome);
 });
 });
 });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="bar bar-header bar-positive" style="margin-bottom:80px;">
 <a href="index.html" class="button button-clear">Home</a>
 <h1 class="title">Read Database (JSON)</h1>
 </div><br/><br/>
 <ul class="list" id="listview">
 </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

getDados.php

```html
<?php

function conectar(){

define('HOST','localhost');
define('USER','root');
define('PASS','');
define('BASE','db');

try{
    $conexao = 'mysql:host='.HOST.';dbname='.BASE;
        $conexao = new PDO($conexao, USER, PASS);
        $conexao->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        // echo 'Conectado com sucesso';
} catch (PDOException $erro){
    echo $erro->getMessage();
}

return $conexao;
}
?>
```

ajax.php

```html
<?php
header('Content-Type:' . "text/plain");
include_once "getDados.php";
$pdo = conectar();

    $listar = $pdo->query("select * from cad_cliente");
    $listar->execute();


echo json_encode($listar->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ));


?>
```

Comment: Coloque na pergunta qual é o resultado do ajax...

Comment: Ele mostra os dados no console.log?

Answer (score 0):

Se mostra o retorno no console talvez não esteja retornando um objeto... tente  ver que tipo de elemento esta retornando.

```
console.log(typeof result);
```

Se for do tipo `string` e estiver no formato de `JSON` é só fazer o `parse` com `JSON.parse` e depois usar ex:

```
 var result = JSON.parse(result);
```

Isto vai converter uma string no formato `JSON` para um objeto `javascript` dai pode proceder normalmente.